# how to assign a list to a specific row and column in openpyxl?

Tags: python, list, openpyxl

I want to assign a list to excel and I use this code:

```
lst = [50, 56, 62, 68, 74, 80, 86]

for i in zip(lst):
     sheet.append(i)
```

and the output is my list assigned in the first column.

how can I assign that list to a specific row and column?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cell's value directly using `ws['A1'] = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 21)`.

Or you can iterate through cells and set their values like this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=2):
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = new_value
```